# How to round the brush selection to 10 or 10k in DC.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Using D3, crossfilter and DC, I would like to draw a barchart with a selection brush.
The dimension of this chart is rounded to the 10k.

```
votesDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return Math.round(d.votes / 10000)*10000; })
```

But the brush on the chart is not.
All I managed to do is round it to nearest integer with

```
.round(Math.round)  
OR
.round(dc.round.round)
```

I'm looking to round the brush to the 10k too.
Does someone knows which function I have to use in .round()?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it :)

```
.round(function(val){return Math.round(val/10000)*10000;})
```

Sorry this looks like a stupid question now. Anyway, I did not find the answer anywhere else, I hope this helps someone else.